# Type Error : cannot read property 'text' of Undefined

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I followed exact same procedure shown by Doug Stevenson. Still don't know why I am getting this error. I am totally new to cloud functions. I am receiving this error:

```
    onMessageCreate
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined 
               at addPizzazz (/srv/lib/index.js:16:17) 
               at exports.onMessageCreate.functions.database.ref.onCreate (/srv/lib/index.js:12:18) 
               at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23) 
               at /worker/worker.js:825:24 at <anonymous> 
               at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

My index.ts file is

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

export const onMessageCreate = functions.database
.ref('/rooms/{roomId}/messages/{messageId}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    console.log(`triggered onCreate`)
    const roomId = context.params.roomId
    const messageId = context.params.messageId
    console.log(`New Message ${messageId} in room ${roomId}`)

    const messageData = snapshot.val()
    const text = addPizzazz(messageData.text) 
    return snapshot.ref.update({ text: text })
}) 

function addPizzazz ( text: string):string{
    return text.replace(/\bpizza\b/g,'')
}
```

And my database is looks like this.

[image: Database of my project]

And to create my database just like doug i used this code in my app.

```
String s1 = myRef.push().getKey();
        myRef.child("rooms").child("pizzachat").child("messages").child(s1).child("text").setValue("What the hack is that?!");
        myRef.child("rooms").child("pizzachat").child("messages").child(s1).child("name").setValue("Fear");

        String s2 = myRef.push().getKey();
        myRef.child("rooms").child("pizzachat").child("messages").child(s2).child("text").setValue("Who puts broccoli in pizza?!");
        myRef.child("rooms").child("pizzachat").child("messages").child(s2).child("name").setValue("Joy");

        String s3 = myRef.push().getKey();
        myRef.child("rooms").child("pizzachat").child("messages").child(s3).child("text").setValue("That's it. I'm done.");
        myRef.child("rooms").child("pizzachat").child("messages").child(s3).child("name").setValue("Disgust");

        String s4 = myRef.push().getKey();
        myRef.child("rooms").child("pizzachat").child("messages").child(s4).child("text").setValue("Congratulations pizza");
        myRef.child("rooms").child("pizzachat").child("messages").child(s4).child("name").setValue("Anger");
```

I don't know Android and Firebase at all. I tried to find help but i didn't get. I started to learn only those modules which will help me to implement my idea.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably writing the `name` node before writing the `text` child.  If you do that, then the snapshot delivered to onCreate will only contain `name` and not `text`.  You will need to commit both child nodes at the same time so that onCreate will pick up both of them when the message node is created.  Be sure to do that exactly as shown in the video.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As you said may be i am not committing both values at same time. I have updated my question with code i used to create database. So can you please read that and help me?

Comment: @AnirudhdhsinhJadeja: you have accepted Doug's answer, so readers will assume your problem is solved. If Doug's answer was helpful (because it helped you solve one problem and now you have another problem) then ask a new question. If Doug's answer did not help at all, then please edit your question to clarify the problem (and unaccept the answer).